# 12V DC relay control from raspberry pi

Tags: relay

[image: my reference circuit]

please ignore the lamp and 220vAC supply
when i use 12v DC insted of 5v and changed relay to 12v the circuit doesnt work 
how to use the circuit and modify it to work for 12v.
i need to connect and disconnect 2 points(for controlling my 3d printer on and off)

edit:I have connected the circuit exactly like the circuit i have given (i dont really know to use any software to make the circuit so i havent put my original one but its the same!)
changes i made to this circuit
1. changed 5VDC supply to 12VDC supply
2. changed 5VDC relay to 12VDC relay 
switched on the supply and relay is always ON i.e the relay gets 12V even if i remove the transistor

so my question is 
**will this circuit actually work? Can it be made to work for 12VDC supply with 12VDC relay? IF this transistor as switch doesnt work then can anyone suggest a better circuit?
How to calculate the base resistor value?**

edit2: i had a bad transistor so now i checked the transistor before using it
[image]
**note: i used hfe as 75 is that correct value for using 12v source? how to determine that value from datasheet from the graph**

Comment: What you're saying is "This is a circuit, which has some similarity to mine, but mine doesn't work, can you debug it." In what way doesn't it work? What is your actual schematic? Did it work once, until the transistor was turned off?

Comment: @Colin__s i have edited the question

Comment: added the image i drew with pen maybe someone can suggest me a circuit making software noob friendly ?

Comment: LT spice, its got a learning curve, read tutorials. Make sure you have enough current to turn the relay on, check that in the datasheet of the relay.

Comment: thanks @laptop2d the circuit works i should have checked the transistor first (i should have  not trusted those blindly!!)  i cannot answer my own question i guess the status of the question should be changed...

Comment: MultiSim by National Instruments is also a good simulation tool. Also the hfe is  given in the transistor datasheet, sometimes there's different hfe values for a transistor based on the bin number (also in the datasheet). Use the lowest one first and then the higher values

Comment: Is there freeware or other opensource alternatives?

Comment: http://www.partsim.com/ might be a decent alternative

Comment: If the relay is always on even if you remove the transistor, you have a wiring fault.  A photo of your circuit may help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: dont have to be rude about it...i am no shakesphere and you cannot speak my native language even if you try!! @A.S.

Answer (score 1):

Use ~20 for the hFE to ensure the transistor is deep into saturation. The hFE figures stated on the datasheet are for the transistor in the linear mode and not fully switched on.

So your resistor should be 20*(3.2V-0.7V)/0.03A or about 1.7K. Using 1K or 1.5K should be no problem. Check that the output is really giving you 3.2V under load or check specs on the Pi's Broadcom chip if you can find them.

And check that nothing bad is coming from the base of the transistor before wiring it up (you can common the 12v and Pi supply *grounds*). A wiring mistake could damage the Pi, especially when voltages outside the range of 0..3.3V are involved.